# How to get gettext work on IIS/PHP

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

I have *Windows XP + IIS + PHP (fastcgi)* installed.

I want to use `gettext` for multilanguage application.

**index.php:**

```
bindtextdomain('APP', './locale');
textdomain('APP');
```

**Directory structure:**

```
src\index.php
src\locale\en\LC_MESSAGES\APP.mo
src\locale\ru\LC_MESSAGES\APP.mo
```

The code works only if I setup enviroment variable `LANG` in My Computer's properties (and if I want to change it, I must restart IIS). However when I'm trying to change the environment variable using `putenv('LANG=en')` it does not work.

Is there any other way to tell `gettext` which language to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of PHP are you using? Could it be PHP 5.3? If yes, then check **[PHP Bug #49349](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49349)**.

Comment: Yes, the version was 5.3.1.
Thanks